# How to explicitly convert an ArrayList with Dictionaries into an Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, arraylist

I tried several options, but none worked for me

1.
`Dictionary<string, string>[] profiles = settings.ToArray();` of course throws

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object?[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

2. 

`Dictionary<string, string>[] profiles = settings.ToArray(Dictionary<string, string>);` throws

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0119  'Dictionary<string, string>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

3. 

`Dictionary<string, string>[] profiles = settings.ToArray(Dictionary);` throws

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0305  Using the generic type 'Dictionary<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments

4. 

`Dictionary<string, string>[] profiles = settings.ToArray(Dictionary<string, string>[]);` throws

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0119  'Dictionary<string, string>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Since it was asked:
The definition of settings is as follows:

```
public ArrayList getSettingsOf(string name)
    {
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = PullDB();
        string sql = String.Format("select * from Settings where Name = {0}", name);
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList output = new ArrayList();
        Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            temp.Add("Foo1", reader["Bar1"].ToString());
            temp.Add("Foo2", reader["Bar2"].ToString());
            temp.Add("Foo3", reader["Bar3"].ToString());
            temp.Add("Foo4", reader["Bar4"].ToString());
            temp.Add("Foo5", reader["Bar5"].ToString());
            output.Add(temp);
        }
        return output;
```

`output` later on becomes `settings` due to OOP

I've looked even on the second page of google, but no where found an answer to that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `settings` here? And where does `ArrayList` come in? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you need to use ArrayList? Microsoft [recommend against it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-5.0#remarks). They recommend `List<T>` for homogenous objects.

Comment: (It's possible that `settings.Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>().ToArray()` will work, but only if the `ArrayList` actually contains elements which are dictionaries. Without a *lot* more information, we can't be confident in that...)

Comment: @JonSkeet settings is the ArrayList containing Dictionaries.

Comment: So put that in the question, ideally with a [mcve]. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on how to make your question much clearer.

Comment: @Llama I was not aware of that, but I don't really see the advantage in my case, anyways thanks for the information!

Comment: You don't see the advantage in your case, _even though_ you would simply be able to call `listOfDictionaries.ToArray();` with a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @JonSkeet the definition of `settings` is a little more complicated though, please give me a little time for that, I'll edit the question, but I'm not sure, if that really helps

Comment: (As an aside, I would suggest only using the term "throws" for exceptions - those errors are compile-time errors reported by the compiler; they're not "thrown".)

Comment: *I've looked even on the second page of google* - one of the funniest things I've read in an SO question, thanks for that! 

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the definition of settings.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need it as an array?

Comment: @Llama for definition I need a List that is resizeable, so I chose an ArrayList for that, but to work with it I personally prefer normal Arrays, it's just a personal thing and I didn't find a good answer, so I decided I should help future noobs like me by asking for that, StackOverflow is really useful, thanks to all programming gurus out here :)

Comment: I see. With a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` you have a resisable collection, can access items by index, and can add/remove items as you need to. By then converting your `ArrayList` to an array using `.Cast<...>().ToArray()`, you're creating a new array (albeit only of pointers to the existing dictionary objects) which adds a little time/memory overhead.

Comment: Your `getSettingsOf` method is already broken if you have more than a single row - the `temp` variable should be declared *inside* the loop. (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions, and use appropriate `using` statements for your database resources...) If you only ever have a single row in the table, then you can make the code much simpler by returning a single `Dictionary<string, string>` directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet since the code is really old you may be right. I may have had a mistake in thinking indeed. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is messed up and cannot possibly work; you repeatedly Add the same key to the temp dictionary which is 100% guaranteed to crash at runtime. Even if the column names are obfuscated for SO's benefit you've declared your temp dictionary outside the loop so if the loop runs more than once it will also crash..

..and you hence don't need a loop so don't need an ArrayList

---

If you're keeping the list for some reason, don't use ArrayList class for new development, use List (and look to move ArrayList code to List). If you're wedded to ArrayList, my first thought was in line with JonSkeet's;

```
someArrayList.Cast<Dictionary<string,string>>().ToArray()
```

Consider that multiple levels of generic collections aren't really doing you any favors- it would be better to use a class to hold your data not a dictionary, then you can have a `List<Setting>`

Additionally you can use Dapper to make your query life easier; all that data access code you've written boils down to something like this with Dapper (and it will be immune to sql injection hacking, unlike your existing code):

```
using var c = new SQLiteConnection(...);
var sets = await c.QueryAsync<Setting>("select * from Settings where Name = @N", new { N = "some name" } );
```

`sets` will be an enumerable of Setting. Setting can succinctly be a `record` in modern versions of c#, and look like:

```
public record Setting(String Host, int Port, string User, string Pass);
```

..which is roughly equivalent of a data holding class with 4 properties, that I'm sure your more familiar with:

```
class Setting{
   public string Host{get;set;}
   public int Port{get;set;}
   ...
}
```

There are some helpful differences, records being immutable when declared like that and implicitly comparable to other records - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records

Comment: Of course I replaced the original keywords, with foo and bar since I don't want to leak my original code yet. I assure you it's not 5 times the same key!

Comment: As long as possible I'll stick to an ArrayList, since I don't know how much I end up changing because of that.

Your first solution isn't possible, I tried it, it gives me the following error:
>Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>(EnumerableRowCollection)' requires a receiver of type 'EnumerableRowCollection'

Comment: You need to put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file

Comment: Also I won't change the way I work with SQLite, even though it may be a shorter code your solution isn't really easy to understand for me; I normally code in Python and I'm really just a beginner-level in C#, so I prefer short lines with more lines over long lines with less lines. I just cannot wrap my head around that.  Also my question was just how to convert a given ArrayList containing Dictionaries into a Dictionary-Array, not how to work better with SQLite or how to rearrange my complete code to follow microsofts advice.

Comment: "As long as possible I'll stick to an ArrayList, since I don't know how much I end up changing because of that." The longer you stick with it, the more you will have to change. I'd very strongly recommend adopting more modern practices as soon as possible...

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sure you've seen it before but this one always amuses me.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBle7.jpg ? :D

Comment: @derwookie *my question was just how to convert a given ArrayList containing Dictionaries into a Dictionary-Array* - I trust that that question has now been answered?